# Change and reverse pixel change in bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I'm trying to "encrypt" and "decrypt" images so that i can send them through facebook. ( i shouldnt call it encryption i know, but lets just go with it)

Righ now my approach is to XOR each rgb value of each pixel with a value to "encrypt" and to do it again to reverse.

When i try to reverse it, the image returns with a "pixel filter effect", i can tell it's the image i "encrypted" but the colors are off.

```
String hash = sha1Hash(password);
Random sr = new Random(stringToNum(hash));

final int[] pixels = new int[bm.getHeight() * bm.getWidth()];
        bm.getPixels(pixels, 0, bm.getWidth(), 0, 0,
                bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight());

for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i+= 1) {
            int pixel = pixels[i];
            pixels[i] = Color.argb(
                    Color.alpha(pixel),
                    Color.red(pixel) ^ sr.nextInt(255),
                    Color.blue(pixel) ^ sr.nextInt(255),
                    Color.green(pixel) ^ sr.nextInt(255));
        }

Bitmap newBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), bm.getConfig());
newBmp.setPixels(pixels, 0, bm.getWidth(), 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight());
return newBmp;
```

The bitmap comes from a .jpg and the image i create is .jpg too

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + fileName + ".jpeg");
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
        OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
   ....
```

Thanks in advance!
PS: Should i just try to cipher using JCA and skip the header so that it is still a valid file?